# How to say "custom-made products?"

Tags: translation

Which is the most common way a German native speaker would say

- custom-made products
- tailor-made products
- tailored products

Comment: I think that Janka's answer nicely shows that this question is not answered by just looking at a dictionary and picking one entry at random, so can we please not close this? This is not a dictionary-replacement question, and neither is it about a translation of an individual text

Comment: @sgf On the other hand it provides no context, and the need to guess one does not support finding a good translation either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it was clothing, the expression is *maßgeschneidert*.

> Er kauft nur maßgeschneiderte Anzüge, nichts von der Stange.

*He only buys tailored suits, not something off-the-rack.*

For shoes, it's *maßangefertigt*, but that sounds a bit clumsy because of the three prefixes, so people use the noun *Maßanfertigung* instead.

> In Schuhgröße 50 gibt es ohnehin nur noch Maßanfertigungen.

*In shoe size 15 there are only custom-made products anyways.*

For other items this is also common.

*Sonderanfertigung* means more than the size is special:

> Dieser weiße Anzug mit Schlaghosen war eine Sonderanfertigung für Elvis.

*This white suit with flares was custom-made for Elvis.*

You can use this *Sonder-* prefix as you would use the word *special* in English.

> Wir führen auch Sonderlösungen aus.

*We also do special solutions.*

But be careful, because *Sondermodell* means it's ready-made:

> Der Golf GTI war anfangs als Sondermodell geplant.

*The Rabbit GTI was planned as a special edition initially.*

Comment: Even though *maßgeschneidert* literally is about clothing, it is also used often for other custom-made products e.g. IT-solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Most common translations are

- individuell gestaltetes/gefertigtes Produkt
- personalisiertes Produkt
- maßgeschneidertes Produkt

or

- Produkt nach Kundenwünschen

Depending on context you can also say

- Sonderanfertigung
- Spezialanfertigung

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add a common term for general products to the list:

- kundenspezifisches Produkt